# Hybrid Kapsel Fiori app in Fiori Client Custom

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, sap-fiori

I have developed a Kapsel Fiori app and deployed into Fiori Launchpad, but when I run Fiori Client (custom), the hybrid app does not have the functions of Cordova.

If I build the application directly with Cordova, it works.

Any idea how to deploy hybrid app in launchpad to get Cordova and Kapsel plugins correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Fiori Launchpad does not offer any hybrid functionality, but is more like an entry point for web-based apps; it behaves just like a browser. If you wish to access native features, you will need to deploy the application as a regular Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely get when you say Kapsel Fiori app deployed on FioriLaunchpad(FLP). FioriLaunchpad bootstraps Fiori applications and I don't think it can bootstrap a Kapsel based application (However, If I am wrong kindly share the link where it's documented).

FLP is hosted in a browser so like any browser based application, it cannot utilize the native features. Same is applicable to 'Kapsel Fiori App'.

If you want to use native features and also need FLP then I think best would be to use SAP Fiori Client (which is based on Cordova) and load FLP within that.